# Proving these statements simply with Riemann integral definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

How do I establish the following:

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x^2) dx =  2 \int_{0}^{a} f(x^2) dx$$

and

$$\int_{-a}^{a} xf(x^2) dx = 0$$

I can do it with substitution but cannot do it by plain definitions.

Comment: Hint: discuss the symmetries of the functions

Comment: @PaulEnta Oh, so even-ness and oddness?

Comment: Yes... you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can use the symmetries as proposed by Paul Enta, or do the following:

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x^2) dx=\int_{-a}^{0}f(x^2)dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(x^2)dx.$$

Now, apply $x = -u\implies dx = -du$ for the first integral to obtain:

$$\int_{-a}^{0}f(x^2)dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(x^2)dx=\int_{a}^{0}f(u^2)(-du)+\int_{0}^{a}f(x^2)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{a}f(u^2)du+\int_{0}^{a}f(x^2)dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x^2)dx.$$

You can apply the same substitution to the last integral

$$I = \int_{-a}^{a}xf(x^2)dx =\int_{a}^{-a}(-u)f(u^2)(-du)=-\int_{-a}^{a}uf(u^2)du=-I$$

As we obtained $I=-I$, we can conclude that $I=0$.